# What's a normal price for deploying a smart contract? How to make sure I don't overpay it?

Tags: contract-development, fees

I deployed a contract on the testnet and it costed about $1.

I tried in on the mainnet, it required about $50. Is this normal?

Gas Limit: 1719577

Gas Price: 40

Fee: 0.068 ether

How can I make sure to choose the right fees?

Answer (score 1):

> What's a normal price for deploying a smart contract? How to make sure I don't overpay it?

You should try services like [ETH Gas Station](https://ethgasstation.info/) if you are not sure that you've set the correct `gasPrice`.

Right now `40 gwei` is pretty high price. You can try to deploy your contract even with `1 gwei gasPrice`, it will only consume up to **$1.448**, according to Gas Station and your `gasLimit`. It may also take some time because the price is low, but sometimes even tx with such low price are being included in blocks pretty fast.

---

---

*In my experience for the last couple of days tx with 1-2 gwei gasPrice's were executed in less than 20 minutes: [Example 1](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5fb370fcaea5a978c8437fb66e0a74bb22da0cdb42c5cf5bb38f06ec0e6f3cc3), [Example 2](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb3b2894a51b2989ffe366cf9a2349735e1deb953fdede99494f5c4f217517b56).*

Comment: there is a spreadsheet you can use and see how much gas it would cost to execute on the ethereum network.